# how to get object batchwise(pagination) in ZODB

Tags: pagination, pyramid, zodb, repoze.bfg

my zodb having some objects of user class. user objects are indexed using location attribute. all user obj are indexed with his location. if i searched user with some location will get near about 50 users. want to apply pagination. for first time want 10 users, second time want next 10 users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have "pagination" or "batching" mechanism in place.

Usually writing such mechanism involves doing templates and front end work to have a page selector. For inspiration you can check various Python pagination implementations including this one:

https://github.com/Pylons/paginate

Also note that the question lacks examples of source code and views where the pagination would be performed so giving out a detailed answer is not possible.

Comment: how to fetch batchwise data from zodb database(object database) without ORM?  `query = Eq('geoindex',user.location)
        results = idSearch(query, root)
        if results:
            for localityobj in results.values():
                localities.append((localityobj.geoID,localityobj.name))`

Comment: as in above code i will get all the object from Database but i want this data to be batchwise. means i will pass some start index and end index in between those two number that data should be returned. will it be possible for object database? and how to achive it?

Comment: Please read pagination source code, study the idea, then apply to your own code.